# Не работает @JsonIgnore в Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

(продолжение [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1465951/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-post-%D0%B8-rest-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-spring-security-%D0%B8-spel-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD))

UserEntity.java

```
@Entity
public class UserEntity {
    public static final PasswordEncoder PASSWORD_ENCODER = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    private @Id @GeneratedValue long id;
    private String name;
    private @JsonIgnore String password;
    private String[] roles;

    public String[] getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(String[] roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public UserEntity() {
    }

    public UserEntity(String username, String password, String... roles) {
        this.name = username;
        this.setPassword(password);
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.name = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = PASSWORD_ENCODER.encode(password);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        UserEntity that = (UserEntity) o;
        return id == that.id && Objects.equals(name, that.name) && Objects.equals(password, that.password);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name, password);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserEntity{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

DatabaseLoader.java

```
@Component
public class DatabaseLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final TodoRepo todo;
    private final UserRepo user;

    @Autowired
    public DatabaseLoader(TodoRepo todo,
                          UserRepo user) {

        this.todo = todo;
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

        UserEntity greg = this.user.save(new UserEntity("turnquist", "qwerty",
                "ROLE_USER"));
        UserEntity oliver = this.user.save(new UserEntity("gierke", "qwerty",
                "ROLE_USER"));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("greg", "doesn't matter",
                        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER")));

        this.todo.save(new TodoEntity("Todo1", "todo", false, greg));
        this.todo.save(new TodoEntity("Todo2", "todo", false, greg));
        this.todo.save(new TodoEntity("Todo3", "todo", false, greg));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("oliver", "doesn't matter",
                        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER")));

        this.todo.save(new TodoEntity("Todo1", "todo", false, oliver));
        this.todo.save(new TodoEntity("Todo2", "todo", false, oliver));
        this.todo.save(new TodoEntity("Todo3", "todo", false, oliver));

        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    }
}
```

Ответ на запрос:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "todoEntities" : [ {
      "name" : "Todo1",
      "description" : "todo",
      "done" : false,
      "entity" : {
        "password" : "$2a$10$wrKU8PO2.mCC4aMp7AEdIuSRqZQgSvloQ8K/4boZBjMhRvHioZh4S",
        "roles" : [ "ROLE_USER" ],
        "username" : "turnquist"
      },
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/todoEntities/3"
        },
        "todoEntity" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/todoEntities/3"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "Todo2",
      "description" : "todo",
      "done" : false,
      "entity" : {
        "password" : "$2a$10$wrKU8PO2.mCC4aMp7AEdIuSRqZQgSvloQ8K/4boZBjMhRvHioZh4S",
        "roles" : [ "ROLE_USER" ],
        "username" : "turnquist"
      },
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/todoEntities/4"
        },
        "todoEntity" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/todoEntities/4"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "Todo3",
      "description" : "todo",
      "done" : false,
      "entity" : {
        "password" : "$2a$10$wrKU8PO2.mCC4aMp7AEdIuSRqZQgSvloQ8K/4boZBjMhRvHioZh4S",
        "roles" : [ "ROLE_USER" ],
        "username" : "turnquist"
      },
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/todoEntities/5"
        },
        "todoEntity" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/todoEntities/5"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "Todo1",
      "description" : "todo",
      "done" : false,
      "entity" : {
        "password" : "$2a$10$XrnZXfgkFiTtu8.HCCV5KuiT8m24KlgCNptuLFCqJMnor6ePz2Opm",
        "roles" : [ "ROLE_USER" ],
        "username" : "gierke"
      },
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/todoEntities/6"
        },
        "todoEntity" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/todoEntities/6"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "Todo2",
      "description" : "todo",
      "done" : false,
      "entity" : {
        "password" : "$2a$10$XrnZXfgkFiTtu8.HCCV5KuiT8m24KlgCNptuLFCqJMnor6ePz2Opm",
        "roles" : [ "ROLE_USER" ],
        "username" : "gierke"
      },
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/todoEntities/7"
        },
        "todoEntity" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/todoEntities/7"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "Todo3",
      "description" : "todo",
      "done" : false,
      "entity" : {
        "password" : "$2a$10$XrnZXfgkFiTtu8.HCCV5KuiT8m24KlgCNptuLFCqJMnor6ePz2Opm",
        "roles" : [ "ROLE_USER" ],
        "username" : "gierke"
      },
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/todoEntities/8"
        },
        "todoEntity" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/todoEntities/8"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/todoEntities"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/todoEntities"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 6,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Что делать?

Comment: Попробуйте поставить `@JsonIgnore` над методом `getPassword`.

Comment: Не помогло. Пароль всё равно выводиться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил очень просто! Достаточно было импортировать правильную либу (`import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;`). Проблема решена!